# Type mismatch of same type

Tags: java, generics, type-constraints

I'm currently trying to start on a project for one of my CS courses, and I didn't even get five minutes in before I was hit with a rather perplexing error. My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> implements IMergeSorter
{
    private List<T> arrayStore;
    private List<T> temp;
    private int arrSize;

    @Override
    public <T extends Comparable<T>> int sort(List<T> list) 
    {
        arrayStore = list;
        return 0;
    }
```

The issue i'm having is with the first line in the sort method,

```
arrayStore = list;
```

with Eclipse giving me the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<T extends Comparable<T>> to List<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Notes:
The method itself was provided to me by my professor, and the only things I have done with this class are add the three variables at the top, change the class' generic type (it was originally (T), which I changed to (T extends Comparable(T)), and add the one line in the "sort" method. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By having the `<T extends Comparable<T>>` type declaration in the method signature, you're introducing a second type variable `T` which, although it has the same name, is not the same as the one in your class declaration.

To fix, remove the type declaration from your method signature:

```
public int sort(List<T> list) 
{
    arrayStore = list;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That declaration did seem a bit out of place. Not that I'm surprised; my professor's code almost never works right off the bat, we students always have to change something to make it functional. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think simply remove `<T extends Comparable<T>>` from method is not enough because it is a override method but there's no type declaration in interface `IMergeSorter`, I added a new answer as a supplement

Comment: Your answer is great but I'm not guessing, no matter how interface is declared, code `public class MergeSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> implements IMergeSorter {
    @Override
    public int sort(List<T> list) {
        return 0;
    }
}` will not compile.

Comment: @shizhz You're right. Need the type parameter in `implements IMergeSorter<T>`. +1

Answer (score 1):

From your code I think simply remove `<T extends Comparable<T>>` from your method is not enough because it is a `override` method but there's no type declaration in your interface `IMergeSorter`.

I don't know your `IMergeSorter` declaration but it could be:

```
public interface IMergeSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {
 int sort(List<T> list);
}
```

And then your `MergeSorter` should be:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class MergeSorter<T extends Comparable<T>> implements IMergeSorter<T> {
    private List<T> arrayStore;
    private List<T> temp;
    private int arrSize;

    @Override
    public int sort(List<T> list) {
        this.arrayStore = list;
        return 0;
    }
}
```